# Add Copyright As a New Member to Get-Process

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a PowerShell script, which contain:
1. `$GetP`: Variable which is (Get-Process Command)
2. `$path` and `$getfile`: is two variable for getting all process paths in `$GetP` Path.
3. the `foreach` syntax: is a method to getting all paths in $getfile (LegalCopyright).
...
Now I want to Add **Copyright** As a New Member to `$GetP` or `Get-Process` for each paths.

**Her's my Wrong Syntax:**

```
$GetP = Get-Process

$path = $GetP | select -ExpandProperty  Path
$getfile = dir $path -Include *.* -recurse 

foreach ($iffile in $getfile)
{

        $fname = $iffile.FullName
        $vfile = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($fname)
        $Copyright = $vfile.LegalCopyright

        #$Copyright

} 


$FileCopyRight = foreach ($Copyright in $GetP) {
    $fpmvar = $vfile.LegalCopyright
    $Copyright | Add-Member -NotePropertyName CopyRight -NotePropertyValue $fpmvar -PassThru
  }


$GetP | select CopyRight
```

Note: When you remove the '#' comment in `$Copyright`, it will show you all CopyRights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do one process at a time or link the variables together with ex. hashtable. Atm. `$copyright` will only be the value of the last file in the `$getfile`-array.

I would recommend running a loop for each process, add the Copyright to that Object and go on to the next one.

Try:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
    #If path is defined
    if($_.Path) {
        $CopyRight = (Get-Item $_.Path).VersionInfo.LegalCopyright
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName "CopyRight" -NotePropertyValue $CopyRight -PassThru
    }
} | Select Name, CopyRight
```

Sample output:

```
ApMsgFwd              Copyright (C) 2006-2014 Alps Electric Co., Ltd.                   
ApntEx                Copyright (C) 1998-2014 Alps Electric Co., Ltd.                   
Apoint                Copyright (C) 1999-2015 Alps Electric Co., Ltd.                   
ApplicationFrameHost  © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.                     
AppVClient            © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.                     
AppVStreamingUX       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.         
armsvc                Copyright © 2013 Adobe Systems Incorporated.  All rights reserved.
....
```